# Grabbing specific anchor nested in lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble grabbing certain text from an  tag. I have the following code:

```
<ul class="listclass">
     <li>
          <ul class="subclass">
               <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a class="last" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">Section Title</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <ul class="subclass">
               <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a class="last" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">Section Title</a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <ul class="subclass">
               <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a class="last" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#">Section Title</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

So I simply want to be able to click on any "Link 1" and get the corresponding "section title" in that specific "li"

I've tried:

```
$('ul.listclass li a').click(function() {
if (!$(this).hasClass('last')) {
    var sectionTitle = $(this).closest('ul.listclass').find('a').text();
    alert(sectionTitle);
}
});
```

I just can't seem to grab that text because there isn't an association with it. And when I try to use it using "li" it just grabs "Link 1"

Comment: You have no class called `.product-list`, change it to `.subclass`and it'll alert "Link1Link2"

Comment: my bad, I changed it. I don't want link1link2 though. I want the text that says "section Title"

Comment: Umm... thanks? I didn't know that my code was wrong. That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.closest('ul.listclass').find('a').text();
```

is going to the top level, not the level you are at. You want to go up to subclass and look for the sibling of it that has the section title.

```
.closest('ul.subclass').next('a').text();
```